# Xsane doesn't find network scanner (printer works)

Tags: printing, scanner

I have an HP Deskjet 1050 j410 all in one setup as a network printer/scanner on a raspberry pi. My laptop running ubuntu 16.04 finds the printer and scanner and it all works. All I had to do was edit `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` and put the ip address of the pi. On my desktop also running ubuntu 16.04 the printer is found and works, but xsane doesn't find the scanner. I also edited the `/etc/sane.d/net.conf` file to include the ip address of the pi and it doesn't find it. Where can I go from here? Is there another file I can edit to help xsane find the scanner?

Comment: You can try my answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724366/xsane-fails-to-open-device-invalid-argument although that was for a Canon.

Comment: The @Dor answer worked better for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084235/scanner-not-detected-by-simple-scan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue (works on one computer and not another). The resolution was to make sure HPLIP was set up on the non-working one. Here's what worked for me:

```
apt-get install hplip python3-pip simple-scan
pip3 install pyqt5
hp-setup
```

**Update**

There's an even simpler way which can avoid the pyqt5 requirement:

```
apt-get install hplip simple-scan
simple-scan $(hp-makeuri SCANNER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP | grep ^SANE | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Substitute the hostname or IP address of your scanner instead of `SCANNER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP`

See here for more ideas: https://chrisjrob.com/2016/01/02/ubuntu-simple-scan-hp-all-in-one/