# Trying to get Xsane and a CanonScan LiDE 400 to play nice

Tags: scanner, canon, sane, xsane

I'm experiencing a similar issue as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724366/xsane-fails-to-open-device-invalid-argument).

I've installed SANE. Made sure I'm all up to date with everything

```
  $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Calculating upgrade... Done
  0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

FYI

```
  $ uname -r
  5.4.0-77-generic
```

It detects okay:

```
  $ scanimage -L
  device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60062' is a ESCL LiDE 400 HTTP flatbed scanner
```

But I get this:

```
  $ scanimage -T 
  Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.
  scanimage: open of device pixma:04A91912_44D865 failed: Invalid argument
```

Or this:

[image]

There was one port that seemed to be acting up. As fast as I could type `lsusb` it would have a new device ID. I've added myself to the relevant groups as advised in some forums/questions.

I got desperate and tried `sudo xsane`. No different. Which seems to rule out permissions errors. I specifically selected the LiDE 400 as it was listed as fully supported.

I can assure you that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241451/145472) did not work. `sudo apt remove ippusbxd` was not the droids I was looking for.

Meanwhile `sudo sane-find-scanner` reports a pipe error and no other useful data.

I tried installing Canon's driver and adding it to the conf as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223113/145472). Unplugged USB replugged it. Nadda.

All [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223113/145472) got me was an extra line thus:

```
  $ scanimage -L
  device `pixma:04A91912_44D865' is a CANON CanoScan LiDE 400 multi-function peripheral
  device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60062' is a ESCL LiDE 400 HTTP flatbed scanner
```

Whatever way I go, I seem to hit a brick wall.

What else can I try?

**Update:** after faffing with pulling the USB out and putting it in again somewhere else, I was able to get Document Scanner to see the scanner but it failed to connect, gave an error, and gave up. It is clearly there. It clearly can be activated. What is stopping Ubuntu from using it?

**Update #2:** Wondered if it could be a restrictive firewall issue. Tried `sudo ufw allow saned` to no avail.

**Update #3:** In a fit of desperation, I rebooted. Result - convincing Ubuntu there is a scanner at all is my current problem. Now if only there were a record of my steps so far...

**Update #4:** Xsane loaded!! I guess letting it just sit there for a bit helped. Of course, it was not long until:

[image: I/O Error]

I gave Document Scanner a go too but:

[image: Failed to scan]

**Update #5:** I have fully eliminated the cable and the scanner itself as being at fault. I did this by hooking it up to a Windows PC and installing the driver. I was able to get scans right away.

Comment: I had problems with a networked Canon printer until I allowed its ip address through ufw. `ufw allow saned` did not work for me either. I don't know if this can be an issue with usb, have never used a usb scanner. Did you try a scan with ufw completely turned off.? That worked for me, pointing to ufw as the problem. I also use the `sane-release` ppa on our 18.04 systems, without it, the document feeder will not work on the scanner.

Comment: Mines a flatbed. If it would scan at all, I'd be happy. I'll try ufw off and see what I get.

Answer (score 4):

> device `escl:[http://127.0.0.1:60062'](http://127.0.0.1:60062%27) is a ESCL LiDE 400 HTTP flatbed scanner

The scanner is detected by the SANE `escl` backend. This is good. What is not good is that it does not work. This is probably a bug in your version of the backend (provided `ippusbxd` is not on the system and misbehaving).

Fortunately, there is the independent `sane-airscan` backend to fall back on. On Ubuntu 21.04 it is available and installed by default. What you do on 20.4 is go [here.](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) Note the support for your scanner.

Now you move on to [this page](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/) and download and install `ipp-usb` and `sane-airscan`. `ipp-usb` is much, much better then `ippusbxd`. Even the author of`ippusbxd` says his software is not fit for the job.

Comment: Any positive or negative feedback to the answer would help other users. Silence is golden - sometimes.

Comment: After installing ipp-usb I was able to use xsane.  I also installed sane-airscan from source, not sure if that had any affect..